# Using standard iOS images in UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am looking for a way to use the standard iOS image resources through my application. For instance I would like to place the DisclosureIndicator icon in an image view of mine. How would you go about using the standard resources in iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it would be considered a private API to use iOS resources within your app but I would check out this project [art work extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) which will allow you to extract art from existing native iOS applications and you can include them in your project. Be sure to run this in the retina version to get the @2x versions.

Comment: No problem. This app also generates some very high quality rounded buttons if you need them as well. It is an asset for developers who want native looking graphics but don't have artistic ability